# how to find all leaves of group with javascript and json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to list all leaves ids where group name is i.e. "group110"
So, output for this example is 014, 288, 223 and 244.

Here is content of my JSON file:

```
{
 "name": "visualization",
 "children": [
        {
         "name": "group100",
         "children": [
                {
                 "name": "group110",
                 "children": [
                        {
                         "name": "group111",
                         "children": [
                                        {"id":"014","link":"-","name":" Animals/70","decade":"-"}
                                ]
                        },
                        {
                         "name": "group112",
                         "children": [
                                        {"id":"288","link":"-","name":"Heidelberg platen press","decade":"1960s"}
                                ]
                        },
                        {
                         "name": "group113",
                         "children": [
                                        {"id":"223","link":"-","name":"Camera Praktica Super TL – shutter release","decade":"1960s"},
                                        {"id":"244","link":"-","name":"Mechanical calculator, Facit","decade":"1950s"}
                                ]
                        }
                        ]
                },
```

Comment: Please include your script code as well!

Comment: until now, i have only readFile: function readFile(fileName){
                data = d3.json(fileName, function(error, root) {
                    if (error) return console.error(error);
                                    
                }); 
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way. Find the group using a recursive method and collect leaf nodes using another recursive method.

```
function getLeafNodes(leafNodes, obj){
    if(obj.children){
        obj.children.forEach(function(child){getLeafNodes(leafNodes,child)});
    } else{
        leafNodes.push(obj);
    }
}

function findIds(json,name){ 
   if(json.children){       
        if(json.name==name)  {
           var leafNodes = [];   
           getLeafNodes(leafNodes,json);
           console.log(leafNodes.map(function(leafNode){ return leafNode.id; })); //Logs leaf node ids to the console
        } else {
           json.children.forEach(function(child){                               
              findIds(child,name);
           });      
        }   
   }
}
```

Execution of following code will print `["014", "288", "223", "244"]`

```
findIds(actualJSON,"group110");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code traverses the tree recursively. If `param` has `children`, then its `children` will be traversed. Otherwise, its `id` will be appended to the `results` array, thus, at the end `results` will contain the `id` of the leaves. `getResults` returns `results` to simplify its usage.

```
var results = [];

function getResults(param) {
    if (!!param.children) {
        for (var child in param.children) {
            getResults(param.children[child]);
        }
    } else {
        results[results.length] = param.id;
    }
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic terse recursive answer for finding nodes using some jquery ($.map).
Watch out for stack overflows if the data is deep though!
Also it will not continue searching inside a matching node for more matching sub  nodes, so it's only applicable if the search term does not nest logically.
This method makes use of the array flattening feature of $.map.

```
var found = (function walk(obj, searchKey, searchTerm) {
   if(!$.isPlainObject(obj)) return null; 
   return obj[searchKey] === searchTerm ? [obj] : $.map(obj, function (lev) { 
       return walk(lev, searchKey, searchTerm); 
   }); 
})(data, 'name', 'group110');
```

Expanding on that to solve the specific problem above...

```
var found = (function walk(obj, searchTerm) { 
   if(!$.isPlainObject(obj)) return null;
   return obj.name == searchTerm 
            ? $.map(obj.children, function(c){ 
                  return $.map(c.children, function(f){ return f.id; }); })
            : $.map(obj.children, function (lev) { 
                  return walk(lev, searchTerm); }); 
})(data, 'group110');
```

Or rather

```
var found = (function walk(obj, lambda, term) { 
   if(!($.isPlainObject(obj) || $.isArray(obj))) return null;
   return lambda.call(obj, term) 
            ? $.map(obj.children, function(c){ 
                  return $.map(c.children, function(f){ return f.id; }); })
            : $.map(obj.children, function (lev) { 
                  return walk(lev, searchTerm); }); 
})(data, function(a){ return this.name == a; }, 'group110');
```